# Как запустить Rails-приложение на вебсервере Puma без порта?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Запускаю сайт командой: `puma -e development -p 3000 -d`

Она работает но как правильно пишется вариант без порта? А то без явного указания порта на сайт не зайти.

**UPD**

пытаюсь запустить просто указывая 80 порт puma -e development -p 80 -d у меня просто на этом порту nginx страница открывается.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здесь много нюансов.

#### 1. "Без порта" браузер обращается на порт 80

Поэтому вам нужно повесить сервер на порт 80, порт по умолчанию для HTTP.

#### 2. ...но занимать порты <1024 можно только суперпользователю

...или кому-то, кому явно дали такие полномочия.

#### 3. ...но так обычно не делают

Более того, если у вас в системе стоит пакет вебсервера, вроде Apache или **nginx** (ваш случай!), скорее всего этот порт уже занят и Puma не запустится, пока вы его не освободите. Да, даже с правами суперпользователя занять один TCP-порт двумя процессами нельзя.

...обычно на настоящий порт 80 выставляют не сам сервер приложения, а обратный прокси перед ним. Чтобы он мог осмысленно отвечать даже тогда, когда сервер приложения лежит. Поэтому оставьте на 80-ом nginx, но настройте его  на роль обратного прокси для Puma.

#### 4. ...и технически можно запустить сервер без порта вообще

...но и снаружи он тогда доступен не будет. Это можно сделать, запустив сервер на Unix domain socket с помощью ключа `-b unix://путь-к-сокету`. А после можно настроить обратный прокси, чтобы направлял запросы к приложению в этот сокет.