# Вызов nodejs скрипта без указания порта

Tags: node.js

Мне необходимо обращаться к скриптам nodeJS по URL, то есть, чтобы адрес не содержал порт.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Очень-очень-очень сильно похожий вопрос, но рядом с Ruby: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/634528/181100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа.

Первый - в коде найти места, где написано `listen(8080);` или что то подобное и заменить там порт на 80.

Второй - настроить nginx/apache как прокси. Ищется по словам "nginx nodejs proxy". Вот [пример](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: 80-ый порт занят апачем

Comment: @dakemu значит, никак, т. к. отсутствие порта для HTTP означает порт 80 :) Ну, или настроить апач так, чтобы он работал проксёй для вашего Node.js, но технически запросы будут всё равно приходить сначала апачу.

Comment: если это тесты на локалхосте, то можно провернуть следующий трюк - биндиться не на 127.0.0.1, а на 127.0.0.2 или любой другой.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле порт 80 можно не трогать. Если на хостинге уже стоит Apache, тогда достаточно в файле `.htaccess` прописать:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://yourdomain.com:ХХХХ/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com:ХХХХ/$1 [P,L]
```

где ХХХХ — ваш порт в приложении NodeJS, а yourdomain.com — ваш домен