# Как заставить работать Node JS через 80 порт?

Tags: node.js

Здравствуйте. Можно ли как-то заставить работать сервер на Node JS через 80 порт?

Comment: А может, [не надо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/634528/181100)?

Comment: @D-side подскажите, пожалуйста, как тогда можно взаимодействовать Node JS (socket) и сайт (порт 80)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На уровне web-сервера (например, nginx) проксируете запросы на тот порт, на котором работает Node JS. Или вы хотите самостоятельно написать полноценный web-сервер уровня nginx?)

Comment: зачем нужен "уровень нгинкс" если используется простое прокси?

Comment: как можно проксировать запросы? ни разу этим не занимался

Comment: @ikerya все мы делаем когда-то в первый раз, например, используйте в конфиге nginx "proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;", где 3000 - порт на котором у вас работает node server

Comment: @eri тогда что будет на фронте? или вы предлагаете сразу к фронту подключить сервер node?

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov а если у меня apache?

Comment: @ikerya ставите сервер нода в директиве "<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:3000></VirtualHost>" но не рекомендую держать Apache на фронте, это достаточно тяжелый сервер. Лучше его поставить на бэкенд и проксировать на него все запросы с nginx (а если вы пишите на чистом ноде, то apache можно убрать и проксировать запросы с nginx напрямую на сервер нода).

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov понял, благодарю

Comment: Я о том,что дело не в уровне и производительности фронта. При работе просто проксей фронт просто не даст умереть бэку при перегрузке. В нормальном режиме плюсов никаких в проксипасс. Идея поставить фронт тем не менее хороша, ведь потом будет проще переделать на пул серверов и закешировать статику в гзипе

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант это напрямую запустить демон на 80 порте. Для этого надо убедиться, что 80 порт никто не занимает.

Но как уже сказали выше, правильнее установить nginx и перенаправлять запросы с 80 порта на любой порт.

PS Так же не забываем про запасной порт 8080.